# Applying styles etc. to selected LIstBox item in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

Consider a simple listbox:

```
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyNormalForegroundBrush" Color="White"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyNormalBackgroundBrush" Color="Black"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MySelectedForegroundBrush" Color="Purple"/>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MySelectedBackgroundBrush" Color="Yellow"/>
            </ListBox.Resources>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource MyNormalForegroundBrush}"  BorderThickness="5" Background={StaticResource MyNormalBackgroundBrush}>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Foreground="{StaticResource MyNormalForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

How can I get the border brush, background, and textblock text foreground to change color for the currently selected item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the ways provide for you, when the selected item changed, get the current selected item, and then [find the control in DataTemplate by element name](http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html), after you got the controls, you can change the control style